# RestKit Custom Data Structure

Tags: restkit, restkit-0.20

I need to consume a web service with non-key-differentiated responses like this:

```
"data": [
    {
      "type": "sometype",
      "id": "1",
      "attributes": {
        "att1": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam ac dapibus nibh. Nam neque neque, volutpat nec sem ut, hendrerit porta felis.",
        "att2": null,
        "att3": null,
        "att4": null,
        "att5": null
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "sometype",
      "id": "2",
      "attributes": {
        "att1": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam ac dapibus nibh. Nam neque neque, volutpat nec sem ut, hendrerit porta felis.",
        "att2": null,
        "att3": null,
        "att4": null,
        "att5": null
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "sometype",
      "id": "3",
      "attributes": {
        "att1": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam ac dapibus nibh. Nam neque neque, volutpat nec sem ut, hendrerit porta felis.",
        "att2": null,
        "att3": null,
        "att4": null,
        "att5": null
      }
    },
  ]
```

Where `SomeType` would be an `NSObject` or `NSManagedObject` with an `id` property, as well as the other 5 `att1-5` properties.

Is it possible to consume custom responses like this using RestKit where the response of every call is basically the exact same structure?

Comment: Depends what you want to do with the result, which isn't really clear. `sometype` dictates what you should do, what the destination class is?

Comment: I figured this out using `RKDynamicMapping`